# Android - Its a good practice to use dependency dependecies in your code?

Tags: android

If I use Retrofit for example and I need to use OkHttp, then should I include it manually in my dependencies or use the included by Retrofit?

How can I use the version that I want and avoid Proguard errors?

Answer (score 1):

Always use the library that is specified by the other library, unless you have a very good reason for separating them.  That's how you prevent possible incompatibilities between the two libraries.

If you must use a different version, test thoroughly to make sure you're not introducing a bug.